# How do I plot a histogram in R for a table with 'char' and 'int' data types?

Tags: r, histogram

I have a huge data set (3920 by 2) containing different department names in column one ('char') and job listings in column two ('int'). How do I plot a histogram for this (No of positions vs departments)? I do not know the no of unique departments.
Here are a few sample entries from the table.
[Screenshot of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAOZe.jpg)

Comment: I think you want a barplot, not a histogram. And 3920 by 2 is tiny.

Comment: Do not post your data as an image, please learn how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df1 <- data.frame(Agency = c("A","C","C","B","A","B"), Positions = c(1,2,3,4,2,6))

sp <- split(df1$Positions, df1$Agency)
summed <- unlist(lapply(sp, sum))

barplot(summed, main="Agency", ylab="Positions", 
        xlab="Agency")
```

I split data by Agency, after that I sum it up, and plot it by barplot, not histogram.